# включение макросов access

Tags: vba, access, sharepoint

Макрос VBA должен подготовить данные в файле Excel к загрузке, подрубиться к каталогу Share Point, в котором лежит файл база access, и в access запустить макрос уже на импорт данных к себе в БД из файла Excel.

На этапе подключения к файлу access получаю ошибку 2538, связанную с тем что макросы в access "выключились". Если зайти вручную в access перед запуском и Включить макросы, а затем запустить макрос в Excel - все отработает корректно.

Пробовал ставить в access галочку напротив пункта Параметры макросов => Включить все макросы, это помогает лишь временно. Через несколько запусков ошибка воспроизводится (макросы снова "выключаются"). Пробовал добавить папку Загрузки (куда во время отработки макроса VBA временно скачивается access) в Надежные расположения - это решает проблему, но после того как я сохраняю access и загружаю файл с этими настройками в каталог share point, остальные пользователи, скачав access, в списке Надежных расположений папку Загрузки не видят. Как будто при размещении в сети файла access, в нем стираются некоторые настройки безопасности.

Есть ли возможность в момент подключения к access из макроса VBA "Включать" макросы в access, если они там выключились? В документации к объекту Access.Application не нашел похожего метода.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли возможность в момент подключения к access из макроса VBA "Включать" макросы в access, если они там выключились?

Нет, такой возможности нет.
Имейте ввиду что настройки безопасности хранятся не в файле приложения, а в системном реестре клиента.

При необходимости обработать множество клиентов - создаю REG файл и запускаю на каждом.